# How do I disable email sending or route to other email account in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm migrating a site from SharePoint 2013 to Office 365. Want to ensure that no emails/notifications are sent to production user during migration. What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [ShareGate](https://en.share-gate.com/) for migration. Below are the steps I followed during the migration -

1. Add email routing rule in the online exchange like, if there are certain addresses, emails should be redirected to a common mailbox. For example, if any email has the address sp_redirect@mycompany.com in TO or CC then the email should be routed to test@mycompany.com
2. Add sp_redirect@mycompany.com (any email address that has a routing rule associated) in the CC field of the workflows which will be migrated
3. Migrate list/libraries without alerts
4. Migrate the workflows
5. After successful migration remove the email address sp_redirect@mycompany.com from the workflows. And then, add the user alerts in list/libraries. However, one thing needs to mention here is, ShareGate does not support User Aler migration from on-premise to on-line (Office 365)